# Thread performance in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have this following code:

```
  for ( int i = 0  ; i < 100 ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 80 ; j ++)
    { 
     ...
    }
```

i splitted it to 8 threads.

```
pthread_t thread1, thread2,thread3,thread4,thread5,thread6,thread7,thread8;
int rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5,rc6,rc7,rc8;



 struct threads 
 {
 ...
 }

 void *PrintHello(void *args)
 {
   for (int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j ++)
    { 
    }

 }

  for ( int i = 0  i < 100 ; i ++)
  {
    rc1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);,
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    rc2 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
    rc3 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread3,NULL);
    rc4 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread4,NULL);
    rc5 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread5,NULL);
    rc6 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread6,NULL);
    rc7 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread7,NULL);
    rc8 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);
    pthread_join(thread8,NULL);

  }
```

i think, second one should be faster than first one .But, second one   behaves like that there is only one thread.In other words, The 
code that is not splitted  and the code that is splitted  run in same time.
why do they have same run time, while second one has 8 thread, first one has one thread?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?  Also, what platform?

Comment: sorry , ı updated the question

Comment: Your `PrintHello` function is so trivial, that using it for thread timing will not give you any meaningful results.  The overhead of setting up and tearing down the threads is much more significant in comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pthread_join(thread1,NULL);` is going to halt execution of the main thread until `thread1` finishes.  You need to move all of the `pthread_join`s to after you construct all of the threads so they can all run concurrently.

You are also using `thread1` for every `pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,PrintHello,threads);`.  You need to use the other threads as well

```
for (int i = 0 i < 100; i++)
{
    rc1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc3 = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc4 = pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc5 = pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc6 = pthread_create(&thread6, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc7 = pthread_create(&thread7, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    rc8 = pthread_create(&thread8, NULL, PrintHello, threads);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread4, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread5, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread6, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread7, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread8, NULL);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides of what @NathanOliver said, keep in mind that spawning a thread comes at a significant cost, so whatever work you intend the threads to do, it has to be more costly than the penalty you get for actually spawning all these threads. So if your `PrintHello` method actually does exactly that, you will probably still see a performance degradation versus the single threaded version. The usual way these costs are offset is to spawn a finite amount of thread at the very beginning and divide work as it becomes available among them.

Also, last but not least, if your `PrintHello` method actually does only that, ie `printf("Hello\n")` or similar, you will most likely not see a performance improvement no matter what, as `printf()` will most likely take a shared lock which will see huge contention with all of your threads repeatedly trying to take it.

The bottom line is, multithreading is great to improve performance, but it's not trivial. Most of the time just throwing threads at your code is not going to improve your performance at all, and in the worst case will actually degrade it. If you want to see speed ups, you should profile your code and look out for big tasks of work that can be easily divided among several works that can all work independently on a part of the result. Those kinds of work can very easily be multithreaded and can see a increased throughput over single threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @NathanOliver and @JustSid it is not really great to define 8 threads separatly and write 8 times the same code if they all do the same work.
Much better to use something like

```
pthread_t threadlist[8];
int results[8];
```

To initialize it a simple for loop will do.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    results[i] = pthread_create(&threadlist[i], NULL, PrintHello, threads);
```

And start the threads with

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    pthread_join(threadlist[i], NULL);
```

This reduces the code much. Maybe there are *really* slightly changes in runtime but a for loop with an int are only a few more assembler commands. I do not know if this is even measurable.

Comment: Not measurable. Since those loops have a compile-time constant terminating condition and are really short, any compiler worth using will unroll the loops.

Comment: @user4581301, I'd even say, it is BETTER to have the loops, since they could be vectorized while unrolled :)

Comment: Cleaner code would be more my métier. If instead of 8 we had a `NUM_THREADS` of some `const` type, the whole thing easily scales to more threads with the change of a single value. Though he concept of paralellizing the creation of threads is something I find amusing.